# Why can I not upgrade for 12.04 to 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, upgrade, xfce

When I go to upgrade my software the task manager says 0 upgraded 0 newly installed and 0 not upgraded. Also I am using crouton so that my chromebook may support it. I am using xfce.

Answer (score 1):

You don't upgrade 12.04 to 13.04, at least not directly if that is what you mean. You will need first to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 and, if everything goes fine, you have to upgrade now from 12.10 to 13.04

12.04 > 12.10 > 13.04

To be able to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 you first need to go to Software Center>Edit>Sources and in the update tab enable 'Every new version'

Not really sure about xfce but you should be able to enter Software Sources with your package manager or software update settings.

[image]